# Good example of using libpurple?

Tags: c, instant-messaging, aim, libpurple

I have an old machine in my house and one of the things
this machine does is detect whether a particular door in
the house has just opened or closed.

Right now, I have that machine post a tweet on a private
Twitter account.

I would now like to give this machine its own AIM account
and have it send me a message on AIM.  The only messages
that will be sent are literally "front door open" and
"front door closed."

It appears that libpurple is a commonly used library for
dealing with various instant messaging protocols and is
even used in Adium, but it is terribly complicated and
I can't figure out how to use it.

Does anybody have or know of a simple code sample that
uses libpurple?

Answer (score 3):

I personally found the source code of [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/) to be straightforward to read. There are many more IM clients that use libpurple, though, you can check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libpurple#Other_notable_software_based_on_libpurple) for more details.

Comment: libpurple was developed as a back-end for Pidgin, so that should be the defacto place to start. But as you say, there's plenty of others using it now as well.

Comment: After 2 years. Do you think your answer should be updated!

Answer (score 1):

I've done this sort of thing in a bash script before. Unfortunately the code is lost, but you may want to look at dbus as a piece of the solution. The code was relatively straightforward.

[This page on updating pidgin status](http://earlruby.org/2008/08/update-pidgin-status-using-cron/) might be a good starting point.

For your application, it might be as easy as:

```
purple-remote uri 'aim:goim?screenname=yourimhandle&message="front door open"'
```

(Watch the quoting!)

See [purple-remote(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/purple-remote).

Answer (score 1):

I fought through dragons^Wnonexistent documentations and it seems to be plausible:-)
Having some time to hack some stuff together, I think it may worth a quick check.

- Extended purple-remote script:
  http://koshinae.pastebin.com/t7UTReWt
- Stuff using libpurple:
  http://koshinae.pastebin.com/HBQiwpDX -
- Callback script is run if someone
  sends an IM, stdout is written back,
  call this script
  purple-answering-machine.

Important and good to know, that to use the internal DBus services,

1. run this in e.g. screen for a long time :),
2. the purple-remote should be run in
   the same dbus session. I made a
   script that starts a session at boot
   and exports DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
   in all user's bashrc. Feels hacky?:)

Anyone with better skills with libpurple, please halp us out! :-)

Comment: Uh, and the Makefile: http://koshinae.pastebin.com/TPM8en2i

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely take a look into the [nullclient.c](https://gist.github.com/1904343) provided in the libpurple sources (libpurple/example/nullclient.c). It performs logging into server and adds some useful callbacks. To send a message, add this to (for example) the function signed_on:

```
PurpleConvIm im;
im.conv = purple_conversation_new(PURPLE_CONV_TYPE_IM, account, "other@example.com");
purple_conv_im_send(&im, "open door");
```